# Build electron with Yocto

Tags: linux, electron, yocto, arm64

I would like to build electron with Yocto for an arm64 machine.
I use https://github.com/vulcanoio/meta-electron

But when I run bitbake electron I have the followings errors :

cannot map aarch64 to electron architecture

If someone have already build electron with yocto it can help me

Comment: `Last commit date: 8 years ago` - are you really sure you want to use this repo? If yes, that will need most like quite some fighting with recipes.

Comment: With that said, if you look [at the code](https://github.com/vulcanoio/meta-electron/blob/master/classes/electron-arch.bbclass), this error seems to be easy enough to fix: you could change line 10 from `arm64` to `aarch64`, or you could try setting `TARGET_ARCH` to `arm64` in a bbappend (though careful with the latter, that variable is quite a fundamental one that shouldn't be messed with lightheartedly)

Comment: Perhaps i can build a recipe based on this repo. Updating the source uri and target machine

Comment: What I understand is that we need to make a new layer based on meta-browser to build electron for arm64

Comment: Generate Ninja (GN) is a new tool used by the chromium project to replace GYP. Since GN is written in C++, it is 20 times faster than GYP written in Python. The meta-electron is for electron that use gyp